# After lamp install, can't run php scripts on localhost

Tags: apache2, php, lamp

I followed this tutorial to install lamp: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

At step 4: See PHP on your Server, I was told to do the following:

First create a new file:

```
> sudo nano /var/www/info.php
```

Add in the following line:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Then,I should see a page with lots of information, when I type in `localhost/info.php`

But the page is just white. No error message.

If I type in `localhost/index`, then the Apache2 Ubuntu default page loads.

Later, I moved info.php to `/var/www/html` but the page is still white.

At this point, I'm clueless. Any suggestions to fix this problem?

Comment: would you please update the outputs for `which php` &  `whereis php`?

Comment: @AzkerM which php: /usr/bin/php
whereis php: php: /usr/bin/php7.0 /usr/bin/php /usr/lib/php /etc/php /usr/share/php7.0-json /usr/share/php7.0-xml /usr/share/php7.0-readline /usr/share/php7.0-mcrypt /usr/share/php7.0-opcache /usr/share/php7.0-mbstring /usr/share/php7.0-gd /usr/share/php /usr/share/php7.0-common /usr/share/php7.0-mysql /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would rather create a **public_html** folder in user's home directory

```
mkdir public_html
```

By default, PHP scripts in user directories are disabled. In other words you need to enable them. With your instructions, you seem to have php5 installed. To enable PHP scripts in user directories, edit **/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf** file as root.

In my case I did

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf
```

When that file is open, comment out the following lines (instructions inside the file too)

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_value engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

and save it. Make sure userdir is enabled with

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
```

Move that **info.php** file to your **public_html** folder. Restart apache2 with

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Go to http://localhost/~yourusername/info.php and it should work perfectly.

Comment: I tried to follow your steps: I couldn't install php5 so instead I just used the last version. Then, I went to /etc/apche2/mods-available/php7.o.conf and commented the section out (by putting #before the lines). And did sudo a2enmod userdir and apache2 restart. It says: Not found . The requested URL /sandro/public_html/info.php was not found on this server. (Apache/2.4.18)

Comment: @Metaphysiker  If you already installed libapache2-mod-php , try running `sudo a2enmod php7.0`, otherwise run `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php` and then the first mentioned command. After this try restarting apache2 once again and tell me what is the outcome

Comment: sudo a2enmod php7.0: ob for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. And now, I cant restart the apache 2 now

Comment: That's weird because I started everything over and followed steps above and my info.php script works perfectly on apache2 server. Can you reach localhost/~username/ and see if your info.php is there, or what does it say if you try that?

Comment: Thanks for your help! It turns out, that I didnt properly installed lamp. Shame one me.

Comment: Glad you managed to get it work